# Is it possible to Generate new keystore with correct signature using original certificate files

Tags: android, ssl, certificate, android-keystore

Our old developer "lost" the password for the keystore.  We have tried using a brute force attack on the keystore but it has been running for over a week so we are giving up on that option.

We still have the pk8 and pem files which were used to create the keystore.

Is it possible to create a new keystore with the certificate so that the signature matches?

We are at our whit's end on this one. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A PKCS8 file is usually used to hold a private key.  Is the key inside encrypted or not?  If it's encrypted, do you have the password for the PKCS8 file?.  And a PEM file is used to hold a lot of things.  What's in your PEM file?  If you don't have your X509 certificate signed by your CA in that PEM file, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: What keystore? What certificate? What are you using them for?